# "Awaiting Reviewer Scores"after "Minor Revision"

Tags: publications, paper-submission, journal-workflow, peer-review

I have submitted an article (media and communication studies) to a ScholarOne journal. The paper was accepted with minor revision (two reviewers both recommended 'minor revision'). I revised the paper accordingly and addressed the feedbacks. After submitting the revised article for a week, a ADM was assigned and the status has changed to "awaiting reviewer invitation." This status has not been changed for a month. Now, the status has changed to "Awaiting Reviewer Scores." Does it really mean that my paper will go through another round of review with new reviewers? I was told that for paper with "minor revision," it is likely like it will not be sent back to the reviewers. Has anyone experienced similar situation?

I have posted before and received answers saying that "Awaiting Reviewer Invitation" can mean "With Editor." But since the status is now "Awaiting Reviewer Scores", does it mean that my paper has been sent for another around of review?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not a paper has to go through another round of reviews is up to the discretion of the editor. "Minor revision" and "major revision" are gradual, not categorical distinctions and have no guaranteed bearing on how the next round of revision *must* be treated.